# Webview2 in Windows Forms application can't write to userdatafolder but the application can write other files to the folder

Tags: winforms, webview2

I'm creating a webview2 with the code below in a Windows Forms Application. It works on one computer, but on another it can only write the webview2cache folder but no contents. The application user has full permissions and the application is writing other folders and files on that computer in the same location with no issues.

Does webview2 need some kind of special permissions?

```
        string userfolderpath = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)
            .FilePath.Replace("user.config", "") + "webview2cache\\";

        Directory.CreateDirectory(userfolderpath);

        var env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(@"webview2", userfolderpath);
        await webview2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
```

Comment: Try logging the `userfolderpath`. Is it correct? Also, you are using `browserExecutableFolder`. Does that point to a relative path of the `WebView2` Runtime?

Comment: Userfolderpath is correct, it even creates the folder on the affected computer. Plus, the computer it works on has not issues. Same with browserexecutable. But, on the affected computer, I don't see any files being written to userfolderpath.

Comment: Just to try: Change `"webview2cache\\"` to: `"webview2cache"` (without backslashes).

Comment: Still not working. I get the same Access Denied error as before, yet the user as full control of the folder and other parts of the application can write to the same root folder.

Comment: On whim, I moved this to another folder on the impacted computer and it worked. I originally ran this application from the documents folder. I'm not sure if there was a security issue or something else, but it seems fine now.